# How to find the curve whose tangent line is always perpendicular to that of all parabolas centered at x=0 at the point of intersection?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, curves

Basically, I’m trying to solve the following differential equation, but for some reason I’m getting the wrong result and I don’t fully understand why.

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x} = \frac{-1}{\frac{\mathrm{d} ax^2}{\mathrm{d} x}} $$

By $ \frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x} $ I'm referring to the slope of the curve I'm trying to find at every point it has (x,y). By $ \frac{\mathrm{d} ax^2}{\mathrm{d} x} $ I'm referring to the slope of the parabola with the peak at x=0. Since the tangents must be perpendicular one slope must be -1 over the other.

To me it seems like it describes what I mean, however when I try to solve it, I get:
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x} = \frac{-1}{2ax} $$
$$ \mathrm{d} y = \frac{-1}{2ax}\mathrm{d} x $$
$$ y = \int \frac{-1}{2ax}dx $$
$$ y = \frac{-1}{2a}lnx + c $$
Which is not what I'm looking for:
[(graphed x^2 and it's corresponding curve)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRbUq.png)

Sure, they ARE perpendicular, but they aren't perpendicular regardless of my choice of parabola, as in it isn't also perpendicular to, say, 2x^2, at their point of intersection.

I'm sorry if I'm not being concise with what I want to end up with, but hopefully I can clear things up [with this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RACCq.png). As you can see, $ y^2 + \frac{1}{2}x^2 = 1 $ is perpendicular at all points of intersection with any parabola of the form $ ax^2 $

Can anybody please tell me what I did wrong? Considering that my "wrong" result is still perpendicular to a parabola, I don't think that I made a mistake while solving the equation itself, but that rather I'm solving the wrong equation. If that is the case, I wish to know what is the corresponding (or "correct") equation, why, and what is the meaning of the one I solved here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obtained the curve which is perpendicular to the parabola $y=ax^2$, but not to all parabolas. If you want to have the curve which is perpendicular to all parabolas, you have to make $a$ dependent of $x$ and $y$ - at every point, $y(x)$ is perpendicular to $ax^2$ for different $a$.

Indeed you have
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-1}{2ax}, $$
but at a point $x$, $y(x)$ crosses the parabola with $a=\frac{y}{x^2}$. So if we plug this $a$ into an equation, we have
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-x}{2y} $$
and after solving it we get an ellipse.

Comment: But if a is equal to y/x^2 why do we treat it as a constant when we write d(a*x^2)/dx as 2ax? Furthermore, why can't we substitute it before we differentiate if such equality is valid? Why does it change the result?

Comment: When we obtain the equation, we look at the tangents to $y(x)$ and a parabola for a fixed $x$. So even though for different $x$ the values of $a$ will differ, for that particular $a$ the slope is still $2ax$. We substitute $a=\frac{y}{x^2}$ when we are obtaining the equation for all $x$.

Comment: So, basically, you take each point on the curve y(x) (about which we know nothing yet) and you find a parabola ax^2 which intersects the curve at that specific point (achieved when a = y(x)/x^2). Since from the point of view of the parabola a is a constant, then its slope is still 2ax, including at the point of intersection. Then we just substitute and solve it. Correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)